# What is the number of permutations for given N numbers, such that the first part is non-decreasing?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Let $A$ be a list of $n$ numbers in range $[1,100]$ (numbers can repeat).
I'm looking for the number of permutations of $A$ which start with a non-decreasing part, where this part ends with the first instance of the highest number, call this "index $i$" (1 based)from the left. After $i$, the remaining permutation is an arbitrary arrangement.

**Examples**

- For $n=1$ and $A=\{9\}$, we have $1$ way only.
- For $n=2$ and $A=\{2,5\}$, we have $2!$ ways in total.

  - For $i=1$ we have $1$ way $(5,2)$ only.
  - For $i=2$ we have $1$ way $(2,5)$ only.
- If we were given , $A=\{5,5\}$, we have 2 ways totally:

  - For $i=1$ we have one way, namely $(5,5)$, where the first $5$ coincides with first occurrence of $5$ in $A$, and
  - For $i=2$ we have one way, namely $(5,5)$, where the second $5$ coincides with first occurrence of $5$ in $A$
- For $n=3$ and $A=\{1, 4, 3\}$, we have $3!$ ways in total.

  - For $i=1$, we have $2!$ permutations starting with $4$, namely $(4,3,1)$ and $(4,1,3)$.
  - For $i=2$ , $2!$ ways $(1,4,3)$ and $(3,4,1)$ in which $4$ is at $2$nd place.
  - For $i=3$ , $2!$ ways $(1,3,4)$ and $(3,1,4)$ ending with $4$.

To be exact : the number of permutations, without replacement, of given $n$ numbers such that the numbers up to $i$th place from left (say index) are in non-decreasing order, $i$-th place is occupied by first instance of largest number and rest can be random...

p.s. I cannot be more specific...

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is $i$?

Comment: $i$ refers to the place value in decimal system... like 12345, here 5 is at 5th place from the left.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the number of ascending permutations of N"?

Comment: Not exactly... ascending is easier to find, what I'm asking is given clearly...

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways to permute an arbitrary list of $N$ numbers, such that each number will always be greater than the previous one?

Comment: It's a sub-part of the original problem... let me give an example... n=4, {1,1,2,2} then there are 12 ways in which either 2 comes at leftmost. Let's rename these with 2a and 2b , 1a and 1b... then, {2a , 2b 1a , 1b,} is a tuple, and there are 3! ways after fixing 2a. similarly there are 3! ways after fixing 2b at left most... so 6+6=12 ways...

Comment: Could you explain how $314$ qualifies - then I might start to understand what you are getting at.

Comment: @Mark if n=3, {1,3,4}... then number of ways in which left most is largest is (4,1,3) and (4,3,1) neglecting the rest part (after 4). And number of ways in which 4 comes at 2nd place (this counts as 2) (1,4,3) and (3,4,1)...

Comment: I still don't get what you're asking for... Why would you count the ways 4 is first digit or second digit at the permutation, referring to the example {1,3,4}? Considering (4,1,3) as a permutation, it is not of the form you're asking, because the 2nd digit is not greater or equal to all the previous digits.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you are looking for a permutation which has a non-decreasing part ending with the first instance of the highest available number, with the remaining tail being an arbitrary arrangement?

Comment: Ok, I understand the ambiguity... Please read the question again.

Comment: The arrangement $314$ is not increasing, which is why I wanted it explained.

Comment: @Mark yes. U are right...

Comment: Every attempt to describe exactly what kind of condition you apply to the permutation (in the title, in the first paragraph, and after "To be exact") is hard (impossible) to follow. It would maybe be clearer to give an explicit example of a permutation that is forbidden, stating exactly why, and of a permutation that is allowed.

Comment: It seems like you consider $i$ to be given in the problem (it is not a varying index). You just want the sub-permutation at indices $[1,\ldots,i]$ to be weakly increasing?

Comment: I tried to make things simpler by giving $i$ so that the solution would become profound...

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my answer was totally wrong. I'm deleting it.

Comment: $i$ is not given. We've to find solution for all such $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a finite sequence $s$ of length $n$ on integers that range from 0 to 100. Since repetition of numbers is allowed, let's denote with $t^a$ the number of occurrences of the number $a$ within $s$. We also denote with $l$ the largest number within $s$ (I guess it won't always be 100).

Now, assume a given $i$, where $i\leq n$. We want to permute $s$ in a way, that

1. the first $i$ digits are in a non-descending order
2. the $i$-th digit is the first occurrence of the largest number available in $s$ and
3. the rest part of the permutation (from $i+1$ to $n$) is arbitrary.

Let's see conditions (1) and (2): If from $s$ we select $i$ numbers (repetition allowed) where one of them is always the first occurrence of $l$, then this is the same as first choosing the first occurrence of $l$ and then choosing in addition $i-1$ numbers from the sequence produced by $s$ after removing the first occurrence of $l$. The selection of the $i$ numbers will constitute the ordered part of the permutation.

There is only one way to choose the first occurrence of $l$ and there are $\binom{n-1}{i-1}$ ways to choose the next $i-1$ numbers. Now, put $t_1^a$ to be the number of occurrences of $a$ within the selection of the $i-1$ numbers and $t^a_2=t^a-t^a_1$ (the number of occurrences of $a$ that are not in the selection). Finally, let $S$ be the **set** (not multiset) produced by the union of $l$ and the selection of the $i-1$ numbers. Then, for each selection of $i-1$ numbers in $s$, there are
$$\prod_{a\in S} t^a_1!$$
ways to order them in a non-descending manner. So, the first $i$ digits of the permutation can be constructed in $$\sum_{S\subseteq [1,100]~\text{and}~ |S|=i-1}\left[\binom{n-1}{i-1}\cdot\prod_{a\in S} t^a_1!\right]$$ ways. Note, the summation is not over $i$, but over all possible sets $S$. Actually, $S$ is a subset of $\{1,\ldots,100\}$ which always contains $l$ and has $i-1$ elements. Here $i$ is given and fixed.

From condition (3), for each selection of $i-1$ numbers in $s$, the rest of the permutation can be constructed in $$\left(\prod_{a\in S} t^a_2!\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{a\notin S} t^a!\right)$$
ways.

So totally, the number of permutations that satisfy the three properties is
$$\sum_{S\subseteq [1,100]~\text{and}~ |S|=i-1}\left[\binom{n-1}{i-1}\cdot\left(\prod_{a\in S} t^a_1!\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{a\in S} t^a_2!\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{a\notin S} t^a!\right)\right]$$

Finally, if you want to compute this for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, you just sum the last expression over $i$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{S\subseteq [1,100]~\text{and}~ |S|=i-1}\left[\binom{n-1}{i-1}\cdot\left(\prod_{a\in S} t^a_1!\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{a\in S} t^a_2!\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{a\notin S} t^a!\right)\right]\right)$$

Comment: Checking your answer...

Comment: Ok, tell me the answer, as per your formula, for A= {1,2,2,3}... and i ranging from [1,4]

Comment: @AbcDexter, I just noticed. You also want the greatest available number in the multiset to be in the end of the non-descending part of the permutation? In other words, you want it at the $i$-th place? If yes, the solution in **not** what I posted. So, should I change it? Although it is not that difficult to figure it out. You can make a try if you want :)

Comment: change it, as this  looks partially correct for what I was asking... and please give an explanation for {1,2,1,2}

Comment: @AbcDexter I changed the solution in general, because the previous was wrong.

Comment: Ok. Your answer seems to match what I wrote down.

Comment: @AbcDexter If this answer was good enough for you, then you can [accept it](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have $t_i$ times integer $i$, with $i$ from $0$ to $9$. The number of permutations of the tuple $(a_1, \ldots, a_{t_1 + \cdots + t_9})$ with $0 \leq a_i \leq 9$, such that $a_i \leq a_j$ if $i < j$, is $$t_1!\cdots t_9!$$

Comment: I never mentioned the range of numbers... The number in the set ,of N numbers, are in [1,100].

Comment: Ok, then do the math with $i=1,\ldots,100$.

Comment: Ok, but still didn't find the answer...